# How to call a function with keyword arguments by the process function of multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyword-argument

How to call this function :

```
git.Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir, branch=master, progress=CustomProgress())
```

by the process function of multiprocessing module ?

Here I'm using keyword arguments, so I have to pass this process function of multiprocessing module.I want to be called as a separate process like

```
P = multiprocessing.Process(target = git.Repo.clone_from, args = (git_url, repo_dir, branch=master, progress=CustomProgress())
```

Comment: one approach would be to pass a lambda and tuple to `mulitprocessing.Process` and assign the tuple elements to keywords in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Form a dictionary with your keyword args, and pass it in as the `kwargs` parameter to the Process object.

```
P = multiprocessing.Process(target = git.Repo.clone_from, args = (git_url, repo_dir), kwargs = {"branch" : "master", "progress" : CustomProgress()})
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj. The above code after a small change in syntax works:
P  = multiprocessing.Process(target = git.Repo.clone_from, args = (git_url, repo_dir), kwargs = {"branch" : "master", "progress" : CustomProgress()})

Comment: Ah typo, my bad. Fixed the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Suraj. The above code after a small change in syntax works: 
P = multiprocessing.Process(target = git.Repo.clone_from, args = (git_url, repo_dir), kwargs = {"branch" : "master", "progress" : CustomProgress()})